# My nodemcu with tasmota auto disconnect with the wifi

Tags: iot, esp8266, home-automation, esp8266wifi, tasmota

I have a esp8266 which works with tasmota and control some relays, after flashing and configuring the esp with wifi creds. if I go to its given IP it works fine but after 1 or 2 days being connect to the wifi it looses connection and does not re-connect its IP also does not work, to make it work again I have to manually reset it after which it starts to work for another day or 2 and again same problem...

I dont understand what is the problem here!

(my nodemcu is not defected because i have 3 these types of nodemcu working with tasmota and this problem happens in all of them!